# Integer overflow in modular exponentiation function

Tags: .net, f#, overflow

I'm writing a `powMod` function which I have to use quite intensively. The starting point is a custom `pow` function:

```
// Compute power using multiplication and square.
// pow (*) (^2) 1 x n = x^n
let pow mul sq one x n =   
    let rec loop x' n' acc =
       match n' with
       | 0 -> acc
       | _ -> let q = n'/2
              let r = n'%2
              let x2 = sq x'
              if r = 0 then
                 loop x2 q acc
              else
                 loop x2 q (mul x' acc)
    loop x n one
```

After inspecting the range of my input, I chose `int64` because it is big enough to represent output and I can avoid expensive calculation with `bigint`:

```
let mulMod m a b = (a*b)%m
let squareMod m a = mulMod m a a
let powMod m = pow (mulMod m) (squareMod m) 1L
```

I assume that modulo (`m`) is bigger than multipliers (`a`, `b`) and functions work on non-negative numbers only. *The `powMod` function is correct for most cases; however, the problem lies in the `mulMod` function where `a*b` may be over `int64` range but `(a*b)%m` is not*. 
The below example demonstrates the overflow issue:

```
let a = (pown 2L 40) - 1L
let b = (pown 2L 32) - 1L
let p = powMod a b 2 // p = -8589934591L -- wrong
```

**Is there any way to avoid `int64` overflow without resorting to `bigint` type?**

Comment: Try to find a way to do modulo on each one individually before doing the multiplying?  Or, that may not work, but if you can divide by a common divisor, then multiply you may be able to do it.  Unfortunately, anything you do will impact performance.

Comment: It doesn't help. I've already assumed multipliers are smaller than modulo.

Comment: You could use decimal which has quite a large precision, but it's only slightly faster than bigint :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you have is that all of your intermediate calculations are implicitly mod 2<sup>64</sup>, and it's not generally true that

> a·b mod m = (a·b mod 2<sup>64</sup>) mod m

which is what you're calculating.

I can't think of a simple way to do the correct calculation using just 64-bit numbers, but you don't have to go all the way up to bigints; if `a` and `b` have at most 64 bits, then their full product has at most 128 bits, so you can keep track of the product in two 64-bit integers (here bundled as a custom struct):

```
// bit width of a uint64, needed for mod calculation
let width = 
    let rec loop w = function
    | 0uL -> w
    | n -> loop (w+1) (n >>> 1)
    loop 0

[<Struct; CustomComparison; CustomEquality>]
type UInt128 =
    val hi : uint64
    val lo : uint64
    new (hi,lo) = { lo = lo; hi = hi }
    new (lo) = { lo = lo; hi = 0uL }
    static member (+)(x:UInt128, y:UInt128) =
        if x.lo > 0xffffffffuL - y.lo then
            UInt128(x.hi + y.hi + 1uL, x.lo + y.lo)
        else
            UInt128(x.hi + y.hi, x.lo + y.lo)
    static member (-)(x:UInt128, y:UInt128) =
        if y.lo > x.lo then
            UInt128(x.hi - y.hi - 1uL, x.lo - y.lo)
        else
            UInt128(x.hi - y.hi, x.lo - y.lo)

    static member ( * )(x:UInt128, y:UInt128) =
        let a1 = ((x.lo &&& 0xffffffffuL) * (y.lo &&& 0xffffffffuL)) >>> 32
        let a2 =  (x.lo &&& 0xffffffffuL) * (y.lo >>> 32)
        let a3 =  (x.lo >>> 32) * (y.lo &&& 0xffffffffuL)
        let sum = ((a1 + a2 + a3) >>> 32) + (x.lo >>> 32) * (y.lo >>> 32)
        let sum =
            if a2 > 0xffffffffffffffffuL - a1 || a1 + a2 > 0xffffffffffffffffuL - a3 then
                0x100000000uL + sum
            else
                sum
        UInt128(x.hi * y.lo + x.lo * y.hi + sum, x.lo * y.lo)

    static member (>>>)(x:UInt128, n) =
        UInt128(x.hi >>> n, x.lo >>> n)

    static member (<<<)(x:UInt128, n) =
        UInt128((x.hi <<< n) + (x.lo >>> (64 - n)), x.lo <<< n)

    interface System.IComparable with
        member x.CompareTo(y) =
            match y with
            | :? UInt128 as y ->
                match x.hi.CompareTo(y.hi) with
                | 0 -> x.lo.CompareTo(y.lo)
                | n -> n

    override x.Equals(y) = 
        match y with
        | :? UInt128 as y -> x.hi = y.hi && x.lo = y.lo
        | _ -> false

    override x.GetHashCode() = x.hi.GetHashCode() + x.lo.GetHashCode() * 7

    (* calculate mod via long-division *)
    static member (%)(x:UInt128, d) =
        let rec reduce (r:UInt128) d' =
            if r.hi = 0uL then r.lo % d
            else
                let r' = if r < d' then r else r - d'
                reduce r' (d' >>> 1)
        let shift = width x.hi + (64 - width d)
        reduce x (UInt128(0uL,d) <<< shift)

let mulMod m a b =
    UInt128(a) * UInt128(b) % m

(* squareMod, powMod basically as before: *)
let squareMod m a = mulMod m a a  
let powMod m = pow (mulMod m) (squareMod m) 1uL  

let a = (pown 2uL 40) - 1uL  
let b = (pown 2uL 32) - 1uL  
let p = powMod a b 2
```

Having said that, since `bigint`s will give you the correct answer, why not just use `bigint`s to do the intermediate calculation and convert to long at the end (which is guaranteed to be a lossless conversion given m's range)?  I suspect that the performance penalty for using bigints should be acceptable for most applications (compared to the headache of maintaining your own math routines).

Comment: +1 You're right. Detecting overflow cases in `mulMod` and using `bigint` for these cases is the good way to go. BTW, your custom `UInt128` is nice.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method) the following formulas are equivalent.  Your code is using the first, changing to the second should solve the overflow issue.

```
c = (a x b) mod(m)
c = (a x (b mod(m))) mod(m)
```

Hope this helps.

Based upon your comments below - if a <= m and b <= m, and m > sqrt(maxint64), then I'm not sure a solution is possible without going to larger storage.  For large values of m, b mod m will return b, so using the above equivalency formula does no good.

The good news is that you should be able to limit the changes to the single line and retype the value back down to 64 bits [since we know that (a*b)%c should not overflow] before continue on with the calculations.  This limits the expense (in terms of execution performance) to as small a section of code as possible.

Comment: This might help to solve the issue if `b >= m`. But it certainly doesn't solve it in general.

Comment: I am making the assumption that the user could add conditions to ferret out special cases - swap a & b if a > b so that b is always > a, etc.

Comment: No, it's not. I assume `a<=m` and `b<=m` (see my question), but the overflow still occurs. m is quite big in my case, I cannot assume `m < sqrt(maxint64)`.

Answer (score 2):

I know almost nothing about f# however I think you could apply the fact that :

If b odd and `n` such that  `b = 2n + 1`

```
a * b mod(m) = 2 * a * n + a mod(m)
             = 2 * (a*n mod(m)) + a mod(m)
```

and similarly if b is even. You can obviously repeat this as many times as needed on `a` or `n` until you end up with a product that will fit into an int64. I think it is still possible to get overflows if m > maxint64/2.

Comment: +1 for good suggestion. At least it reduces the possibility of overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know F# that well but something like (pseudocode)

```
pmod a b n // a^b % n
pmod a 0 n = 1
pmod a 1 n = a%n
pmod a b n = match b%2
   | 0 -> ((pmod (a) (b/2) n) ^ 2) % n
   | 1 -> ((pmod (a) (b-1) n) * a ) % n
```

pmod is not ok yet but should be used as helper function so

```
PowMod a b n = pmod (a%n) b n
```

You can see that this result will be wrong as soon as  square of result will be grater that uint64 so n has to fit in uint32

Comment: It's another way to write `powMod`, and the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but writing the function this way will make it more generic and convenient to use, it also seemed to be more efficient:

```
let inline pow x n =
    let zero = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
    let rec loop x acc = function
        | n when n = zero -> acc
        | n ->
            let q = n >>> 1
            let acc = if n = (q <<< 1) then acc else x * acc
            loop (x * x) acc q
    loop x LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne n;;

for x = 0 to 1000000 do
    pow 3UL 31UL |> ignore
```

Also, I suppose unsigned long won't be enough?

Edit: The following algorithm is 3x faster than the one above on large bigint since performing less multiplication - might help you choose in favor of bigint:

```
let inline pow2 x n =
    let zero = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
    let one = LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne
    let rec loop x data = function
        | c when c <<< 1 <= n ->
            let c = c <<< 1
            let x = x * x
            loop x (Map.add -c x data) c
        | c -> reduce x data (n - c)
    and reduce acc data = function
        | c when c = zero -> acc
        | c ->
            let next, value = data |> Seq.pick (fun (KeyValue (n, v)) -> if -n <= c then Some (-n, v) else None)
            reduce (acc * value) data (c - next)
    loop x (Map [-1, x]) one;;

for x = 10000 downto 9000 do
    pow2 7I x |> ignore
```

Comment: Be careful on the pattern match, the first thing I did was remove the ' from your code and I had a bug because the last case was _ rather than n and wasn't shadowing the top level definition.